# Real-time charts data in Laravel and Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, database, charts, real-time

I create project with Laravel in back and Angular in front and MySQL and i need help to update Charts in angular without refresh page if data is changed in database.

I try websockets with RestAPI but not result..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.